# Why are there no radiative corrections to the electron charge for (an on-shell interaction)?

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

My question stems from the preliminary discussion of the electron vertex function found in section 6.2 of Peskin and Schroeder's *Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*.

Specifically, they calculate the amplitude for electron scattering from an external potential, taken to be electrostatic and slowly varying. The corresponding potential (by comparison with the Born approximation) is

$$
V(\mathbf{x}) = e F_1(0) \phi(\mathbf{x}) \tag{1} \label{eq1}
$$

where $\phi$ is the electrostatic potential and $F_1(q^2)$ is one of the form factors appearing in the vertex function ($q^\mu$ is the momentum of the photon line in the relevant diagrams).

The book goes on to say (emphasis added)

> Thus $F_1(0)$ is the charge of the electron, in units of $e$. **Since $F_1(0) = 1$ already in the leading order of perturbation theory, radiative corrections to $F_1(q^2)$ should vanish at $q^2 = 0$.**

Why must radiative corrections to $F_1(q^2)$ vanish on-shell? Is it because (1) is the definition of the electron's charge, and thus by definition $F_1(0) = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Here $q^2=0$ means "no interaction" limit - the transferred momentum from/to an external field is zero. $q$ is not an integration (out-of-shell) variable in some loop. In other words, it is sort of a classical limit; thus, the definition of the electric charge.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the limit is not merely that of an "on-shell" transfer: I checked the text and the limit taken is that of all components of $q^\mu$ approaching $0$.

Comment: If $(1)$ is in fact the definition of the electron charge, is it in practice measured and standardized via such a nonrelativistic interaction with a macroscopic electrostatic field?

Comment: Yes, to a great extent, for example, in electron mass spectrometers, etc.